# FedEx API Integration

Tags: php, laravel, api, fedex

I need to integrate FedEx API into my project. I found the JeremyDunn package for this, but on every request I receive the message:

> 1000 authentication failed

I'm using FedEx test credentials keys. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use FedEx\RateService\Request;
use FedEx\RateService\ComplexType;
use FedEx\RateService\SimpleType;

require_once ('credentials.php');

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function test()
    {
        $rateRequest = new ComplexType\RateRequest();
        $rateRequest->WebAuthenticationDetail->UserCredential->Key = FEDEX_KEY;
        $rateRequest->WebAuthenticationDetail->UserCredential->Password = FEDEX_PASSWORD;
        $rateRequest->ClientDetail->AccountNumber = FEDEX_ACCOUNT_NUMBER;
        $rateRequest->ClientDetail->MeterNumber = FEDEX_METER_NUMBER;
        $rateRequest->TransactionDetail->CustomerTransactionId = 'testing rate service request';
        $rateRequest->Version->ServiceId = 'crs';
        $rateRequest->Version->Major = 24;
        $rateRequest->Version->Minor = 0;
        $rateRequest->Version->Intermediate = 0;
        $rateRequest->ReturnTransitAndCommit = true;
        $rateRequest->RequestedShipment->PreferredCurrency = 'USD';
        $rateRequest->RequestedShipment->Shipper->Address->StreetLines = ['10 Fed Ex Pkwy'];
        $rateRequest->RequestedShipment->Shipper->Address->City = 'Memphis';
        $rateRequest->RequestedShipment->Shipper->Address->StateOrProvinceCode = 'TN';
        $rateRequest->RequestedShipment->Shipper->Address->PostalCode = 38115;
        $rateRequest->RequestedShipment->Shipper->Address->CountryCode = 'US';
        $rateRequest->RequestedShipment->Recipient->Address->StreetLines = ['13450 Farmcrest Ct'];
        $rateRequest->RequestedShipment->Recipient->Address->City = 'Herndon';
        $rateRequest->RequestedShipment->Recipient->Address->StateOrProvinceCode = 'VA';
        $rateRequest->RequestedShipment->Recipient->Address->PostalCode = 20171;
        $rateRequest->RequestedShipment->Recipient->Address->CountryCode = 'US';
        $rateRequest->RequestedShipment->ShippingChargesPayment->PaymentType = SimpleType\PaymentType::_SENDER;
        $rateRequest->RequestedShipment->RateRequestTypes = [SimpleType\RateRequestType::_PREFERRED, SimpleType\RateRequestType::_LIST];
        $rateRequest->RequestedShipment->PackageCount = 2;
        $rateRequest->RequestedShipment->RequestedPackageLineItems = [new ComplexType\RequestedPackageLineItem(), new ComplexType\RequestedPackageLineItem()];
        $rateRequest->RequestedShipment->RequestedPackageLineItems[0]->Weight->Value = 2;
        $rateRequest->RequestedShipment->RequestedPackageLineItems[0]->Weight->Units = SimpleType\WeightUnits::_LB;
        $rateRequest->RequestedShipment->RequestedPackageLineItems[0]->Dimensions->Length = 10;
        $rateRequest->RequestedShipment->RequestedPackageLineItems[0]->Dimensions->Width = 10;
        $rateRequest->RequestedShipment->RequestedPackageLineItems[0]->Dimensions->Height = 3;
        $rateRequest->RequestedShipment->RequestedPackageLineItems[0]->Dimensions->Units = SimpleType\LinearUnits::_IN;
        $rateRequest->RequestedShipment->RequestedPackageLineItems[0]->GroupPackageCount = 1;
        $rateRequest->RequestedShipment->RequestedPackageLineItems[1]->Weight->Value = 5;
        $rateRequest->RequestedShipment->RequestedPackageLineItems[1]->Weight->Units = SimpleType\WeightUnits::_LB;
        $rateRequest->RequestedShipment->RequestedPackageLineItems[1]->Dimensions->Length = 20;
        $rateRequest->RequestedShipment->RequestedPackageLineItems[1]->Dimensions->Width = 20;
        $rateRequest->RequestedShipment->RequestedPackageLineItems[1]->Dimensions->Height = 10;
        $rateRequest->RequestedShipment->RequestedPackageLineItems[1]->Dimensions->Units = SimpleType\LinearUnits::_IN;
        $rateRequest->RequestedShipment->RequestedPackageLineItems[1]->GroupPackageCount = 1;  
        $rateServiceRequest = new Request();
        $rateServiceRequest->getSoapClient()->__setLocation(Request::TESTING_URL);

        $rateReply = $rateServiceRequest->getGetRatesReply($rateRequest);

        dd($rateReply);

        if (!empty($rateReply->RateReplyDetails)) {
            foreach ($rateReply->RateReplyDetails as $rateReplyDetail) {
                var_dump($rateReplyDetail->ServiceType);
                if (!empty($rateReplyDetail->RatedShipmentDetails)) {
                    foreach ($rateReplyDetail->RatedShipmentDetails as $ratedShipmentDetail) {
                        var_dump($ratedShipmentDetail->ShipmentRateDetail->RateType . ": " . $ratedShipmentDetail->ShipmentRateDetail->TotalNetCharge->Amount);
                    }
                }
                echo "<hr />";
            }
        }

        var_dump($rateReply);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Fedex is notorious for making bogus API testing credentials. Create a Fedex account and request new credentials.